# Apply to jobs of former company with good relations to current company?

Tags: employer, employment

I work as driver for *Market_X* of *Fortune500_Co*. Last year, *Fortune500_Co* sold *Market_X* to *SmallCo*, and now I drive for *SmallCo*.

*Fortune500_Co* has other markets, and I want to apply to their driver positions.

Problem is that both companies are still working together and have a good working relationship, so *SmallCo* will know when I apply.

How can I apply without *SmallCo* knowing about it?

I don't have any contractual obligations that prohibit me from working elsewhere.

Comment: Can you ask for a transfer?

Answer (score 3):

> How can I apply without SmallCo knowing about it?

A good working relationship doesn't automatically mean companies share their HR information. It's actually quite unlikely.

But in any case there is nothing to stop you applying, everything is above board.

If they really communicate that sort of info if you got the job they'd eventually know, so there's no difference.